# Using Ilmerge to combine multiple dlls in .NET

Tags: c#, ilmerge

Please how can I combine multiple dlls into one using ILMerge.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Currently your question shows no research effort, so I suspect it'll be downvoted pretty quickly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You run it, from a command line, like so:

```
ilmerge /out:Merged.dll Lib1.dll Lib2.dll
```