# How to deploy web service as a single dll? C#

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, dll

I've created a project in VS of type Site. I've created a bunch of asmx services. To make it work on IIS, I just copied cs and asmx files to site's folder. Everything works perfect.
Now, when it comes to deploy my services from local pc to development server, I was told to deliver a single dll.
I don't see how I can compile a dll on this type of project. Is it possible?

Then, I created an ASP.Net project, put all my stuff there. It created a single dll. But if I put it that folder and tell my asmx, that code behind is in that dll, I get parse error when try to check it in browser.

WebService1.asmx:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/AllWebServices.dll" Class="MyNamespace.WebService1" %>
```

Maybe I need to add smth in Class attribute?

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer, what is the other option?

Comment: [What is the difference between WCF and ASMX Web Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448472/what-is-the-difference-between-wcf-and-asmx-web-services)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Asmx webservices deployed on IIS on remote server.

- Right-Click on your project in Solution explorer
- Set Output-type:  `Class Library`
- Build-ASMX WebService Project
- Go to the `bin folder` of your project. You will find dll's there.
- If you have used any `external dlls/libs` and want a single dll you have to merge them, using [Using Ilmerge to combine multiple dlls in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516866/using-ilmerge-to-combine-multiple-dlls-in-net)
- When I deploy my asmx webservice to IIS on remote server. I deploy only

  - `bin`
  - `webservicename.asmx`
  - `Web.Config`

**Note:** You don't need to change the markup in `.asmx` file of your webservice. It will automatically find it in the `dll in bin folder`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did and it give me error, I mentioned in my question. What is written in your webservicename.asmx file?

Comment: <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="WebService.asmx.cs" Class="WebService" %>

Comment: @Chiz you don't need to change the markup in asmx file. try this