# After Publishing Service.asmx file does not updates code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, publish, precompile

I have a website developed in Asp.net and C# with mssql database. I use a web service file named Service.asmx file which contains

```html
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/Service.cs" Class="Service" %>
```

I published the site and give option of precompile. The contents of App_Code turned into App_Code.dll file in a bin folder and so the service.asmx file now refers to incorrect codebehind. And I am getting error "No service defined in Service.asmx ".  How to solve this error.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088747/how-to-deploy-web-service-as-a-single-dll-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks it works fine